# How can I install git version 2.10 with openssl instead of gnu_tls for ubuntu 14

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, gitlab

I have an issue on my Ubuntu 14 system. When I execute this command:

`git clone 'https://gitlab.dune-project.org/pdelab/dune-pdelab-howto.git'`

I receive this error:

```
failed: fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.dune-project.org/pdelab/dune-pdelab-howto.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
```

The repository that I am trying to clone from is a gitlab repository found by clicking this url [dune-pdelab-howto](https://gitlab.dune-project.org/pdelab/dune-pdelab-howto).

I have been reading on this subject and I have yet to discover the solution to the problem. Here are some links and answers that elaborates on the issue:

- [gnu_tls handshake fails connecting to an https server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers)
- [git clone using HTTPS fails with "gnutls_handshake() failed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13909)
- [Compile git with openssl instead of gnu_tls](https://gist.github.com/pescobar/6ae5634f92d75d23c36a)

What seems to be the problem, to my understanding, is that `gnu_tls` needs to be replaced by `openssl` as illustrated by the first link. However, when I try to do this, I can not compile git 2.10 with openssl. The default installation is always 1.9.1 and nothing I do changes that. The proposed solutions in the answer specifies a specific way of installing git as a package but in order to get the most recent, I need to use the ppa. Has anyone had a problem like this before. I'm stuck as to how I can resolve this issue and could use at least a clue to work off of.

Comment: Updating git on ubuntu can be tricky. Try this link: http://lifeonubuntu.com/upgrading-ubuntu-to-use-the-latest-git-version/

Comment: @Briana thanks for the link. This is how I normally upgrade git on ubuntu but the problem I'm having is that with the instructions listed in the url links, I can't build git 2.10 with openssl. The installation process will build it with gnu_tls which is not what I want.

Comment: Not a general solution, but in this specific case you could consider using `ssh` instead of `https` for cloning the repository.

Comment: The git core ppa has been great for me `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa`

Answer (score 2):

In order to compile the latest version of `git` with `openssl` (instead of `gnutls`) and avoid troubles with `gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed` one can use Paul N. Baker's scripts:

https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/git-openssl-shellscript